# MySQL relationship within the same table?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have a web application where you can create a group. A group can be one of 3 options,

1. Organization
2. Client
3. Team

A client group and a team group are relatively simple, however the organisation is a little more complicated.

An organisation can have multiple clients, now my confusion is coming from how do I create this relationship, as the organizations, clients and teams are all saved in the same table. What is the best way to set this up? Should I create a client table that just contains a unique ID and the ID of each client in the groups table, and create a relationship between that and the groups table?

Comment: Why don't you use a table for each group? A table `organisation`, `client`, `team` and insert your data there?

Comment: I had thought about this, but I can visualise how I would get all 3 tables data in to one collection for usage with backbone which is what I need

Comment: I would say that all clients belong to an 'organisation'. An organisation might be a 'team' or a 'company', but (from our point of view) they're basically the same thing. Some 'teams' will have only one member - i.e. 'the client'. In fact, this is exactly how our project database works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand it, your application requires hierarchical groups. In other words, Organization is a group but it also contains another group, such as Client. From your comments, it appears that you want to treat all three as groups.

I can suggest the following table:

```
entity
+ id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
+ parentId INT UNSIGNED
+ type ENUM ('Client','Team','Organization')
+ name VARCHAR(255)
+ address VARCHAR(255)
```

For top-level entity such as an Organization, parentId will be zero. For a client/team group, parentId will refer to the id of an organization group. Actually, any kind of hierarchy is possible with the above definition.

If your columns for different groups need to be different, then you need multiple tables but one table can contain the group hierarchy as noted above.

Comment: Just thought of a caveat - any number of users can create any number of groups and any number of clients can belong to any number of organisations - meaning that the parentID won't work as there is a many to many relationship required i beleive.

Comment: Have three tables: 1. group, with parentId to implement hierarchy. 2. entity, to define actual clients, orgs and teams. 3. map, to create many-to-many relationships between the former two tables. I guess there are many ways to do it.